# In Linear Modelling Why Would I Keep $X_2$ but drop $X_2$ and $X_3$?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I'm having trouble with some intuition in Linear Statistical Modelling.

I'm working with some data with three predictor variables $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$.

I've calculated the $F$ test for whether $X_2$ should be retained in the model containing just $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Similarly I've calculated the $F$ test for whether $X_2$ and $X_3$ should be retained in the model containing $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$.

The conclusion from the first test is to retain $X_2$.  The $p$-value is less than $0.05$.

The conclusion from the second test is to drop $X_2$ and $X_3$.  The $p$-value is greater than $0.1$.

So my question is, is this not counter-intuitive?  How could adding another variable $X_3$ make things worse for $X_2$ than it was with just $X_2$ alone?

My feeling is that I have made a calculation error because it seems the $p$-value should only get smaller with more information not larger.

Any insight into this matter would be greatly apprecaited, thank you!

I can't show you the exact data without getting fired.  But here's a baby data set that illustrates the same issue.  The $F$ test for whether you can drop $X_2$ in the model with $Y, X_1, X_2$ has $p$-value $0.06$ while the $F$ test for whether you can drop $X_2$ and $X_3$ in the model with $Y, X_1, X_2, X_3$ is $0.14$.  So how can it get larger like that?  This indicates you need $X_2$ on top of $X_1$ but you can get rid of both $X_2$ and $X_3$ on top of $X_1$.  To me that's a contradiction.  Am I doing something wrong here?
$$
Y\ \ \ X_1\ \ \ X_2\ \ \ X_3\\
48.0\ \ \ 50.0\ \ \ 51.0\ \ \ 2.3\\
57.0\ \ \ 36.0\ \ \ 46.0\ \ \ 2.3\\
66.0\ \ \ 40.0\ \ \ 48.0\ \ \ 2.2\\
70.0\ \ \ 41.0\ \ \ 44.0\ \ \ 1.8\\
89.0\ \ \ 28.0\ \ \ 43.0\ \ \ 1.8\\
36.0\ \ \ 49.0\ \ \ 54.0\ \ \ 2.9\\
46.0\ \ \ 42.0\ \ \ 50.0\ \ \ 2.2\\
54.0\ \ \ 45.0\ \ \ 48.0\ \ \ 2.4\\
26.0\ \ \ 52.0\ \ \ 62.0\ \ \ 2.9\\
77.0\ \ \ 29.0\ \ \ 50.0\ \ \ 2.1\\
89.0\ \ \ 29.0\ \ \ 48.0\ \ \ 2.4\\
67.0\ \ \ 43.0\ \ \ 53.0\ \ \ 2.4\\
47.0\ \ \ 38.0\ \ \ 55.0\ \ \ 2.2\\
51.0\ \ \ 34.0\ \ \ 51.0\ \ \ 2.3\\
57.0\ \ \ 53.0\ \ \ 54.0\ \ \ 2.2\\
66.0\ \ \ 36.0\ \ \ 49.0\ \ \ 2.0\\
79.0\ \ \ 33.0\ \ \ 56.0\ \ \ 2.5\\
88.0\ \ \ 29.0\ \ \ 46.0\ \ \ 1.9\\
60.0\ \ \ 33.0\ \ \ 49.0\ \ \ 2.1\\
49.0\ \ \ 55.0\ \ \ 51.0\ \ \ 2.4\\
77.0\ \ \ 29.0\ \ \ 52.0\ \ \ 2.3\\
52.0\ \ \ 44.0\ \ \ 58.0\ \ \ 2.9\\
60.0\ \ \ 43.0\ \ \ 50.0\ \ \ 2.3\\
$$

Comment: How big is your data set? Could it be included here?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Hi Michael thanks for looking, I can't share my data publically but I added a toy data set to the problem that has the same issue.  Thank you, Greg

Comment: Common procedures in such cases are (a) forward selection and (b) backward elimination. In (a) try each predictor variable separately, and start with the one that works best (e.g., biggest R-sq), then try including one of the others, if both are judged beneficial, pick the best. Finally, see if it is worthwhile including the third. In (b), start with all 3, if one can be deleted without damage, do so. Then see if either of the others can be deleted without damage. // It is almost always best to use the fewest possible predictor variables; each one that is not crucial contributes variability.

Comment: Especially if you have high correlations among the predictor variables, forward selection and backward elimination will not necessarily give the same set of 'best' predictor variables. Both should be reasonable. If one set works better than the other, choose that one. // Many software packages have procedures for automating forward selection and/or backward elimination (particularly important if you have a large set of possible predictor variables).

Comment: @BruceET Thank you Bruce for your explanations.  I can accept the reality of this, I just wanted to be sure I wasn't making some kind of mistake.  Thanks again!  Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason for this is high linear correlation between $X_2$ and $X_3$. Here is an example:

```
set.seed(111)
x_1 = rnorm(100, 10, 3)
x_2 = rnorm(100, 10, 3)

y  = - x_1 + x_2 + rnorm(100, 0, 17)  

m1 = lm( y ~ x_1 + x_2 )

x_3 = x_2 + rnorm(100, 0, 1)

m2 = lm( y ~ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 )

m0 = lm( y ~ x_1 )

anova(m0, m1)

anova(m0, m2)
```

Another possible reason is if $X_3$ is independent of $X_1,$, $X_2$ and $Y$.

Recall the form of the partial F test
$$
F_{stat} = \frac{( SSRes(R) - SSRes(F) )/ r }{ MSE(F) }.
$$
Denote the model with $X_1$ and $X_2$ by $F_1$ and the model with $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ by $F_2$ and the model with only $X_1$ by $R$.
If $X_2$ is highly colinear with $X_3$ (or $X_3$ is independent of $X_1$ and $X_2$ and $Y$), then although 
$$
( SSRes(R) - SSRes(F_2) ) > ( SSRes(R) - SSRes(F_1) ),
$$ 
it may happen that 
$$
( SSRes(R) - SSRes(F_2) ) / 3 < ( SSRes(R) - SSRes(F_1) ) /2,
$$
while $MSE(F_2) > MSE(F_1)$, hence the partial $F_{stat}$ statistic for the first test may-be significant, while for the second insignificant. In other words, the F statistic is not monotonically increasing function of the number of variables, hence a highly colinear or independent variable that adds nothing but noise - may reduce the calculated F statistic, hence elevate the p.value.

Comment: Hi V.Vancak thank you for your post.  I'm not sure I understand but it seems to me if $X_2$ and $X_3$ are actually equal then there's be perfect linear correlation between them, yet it's impossible that including $X_2$ and $X_3$ could be different from just including $X_2$.  So that seems to be a counter example to your example.  Am I missing something?  Thank you, Greg

Comment: By highly colinear I meant high but not perfect correlation. Maybe, it wasn't the best way to state the bottom line that $F_{stat}$ is not monotonic function of the number of variables. Another reason to such behaviour is when $X_3$ is independent of $X_1, X_2$ and $Y$, hence the model with $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ will be much worse than the model with $(X_1, X_2)$, hence it is possible to get such a result.

Comment: Just note that the MSE depends on the number of variables $p$ through the denominator $(n-p)$, can go up. As such, the value of the partial $F$ statistic can go down. That is it.

Comment: Ok thanks I can kind of wrap my head around that when $X_3$ is independent of $Y$ adding it to the model can only make things worse.  But it's somewhat dissatisfying that our decision on $X_2$ would be affected by $X_3$.  That makes it that much harder to take a systematic approach to building these models.  I want to discuss this with my group tomorrow and will accept the answer then.  Thank you